# How to create legend by line type and colour in stat_function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here I have tried to plot a PDF of 11 variables using ggplot2 and stat_function.I have managed to add legend by colour but I want also to differentiate the lines by line type also and incorporate it into the legend. If anybody could help me with matter I would be thankful? Here is the code:

```
library(gamlss)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

xlower= 50
xupper= 183


    plot1<-ggplot(data.frame(x = c(xlower , xupper)), aes(x = x)) + 
        xlim(c(xlower , xupper)) + stat_function(fun = dNO, args =list(mu= 85.433,sigma=2.208) ,linetype="solid", aes(colour = "Observed"))+
        stat_function(fun = dSN2, args =list(mu= 97.847,sigma=2.896,nu=5.882,log=FALSE) , linetype="solid",aes(colour = "CMCC.ESM2"))+
        stat_function(fun = dIGAMMA, args =list(mu= 4.520,sigma=2.336,log=FALSE) , linetype="solid",aes(colour = "ECEARTH3"))+
        stat_function(fun = dRG, args =list(mu= 93.062,sigma=2.233,log=FALSE) ,linetype="solid" ,aes(colour = "ECEARTH3.CC"))+
        stat_function(fun = dRG, args =list(mu= 94.296,sigma=2.237,log=FALSE) ,linetype="solid" ,aes(colour = "ECEARTH3.Veg"))+
        stat_function(fun = dSHASH, args =list(mu= 112.241,sigma=12.133,nu=9.419,tau=9.743,log=FALSE) ,linetype="solid", aes(colour = "GFDL.CM4"))+
        stat_function(fun = dRG, args =list(mu= 101.101,sigma=2.372,log=FALSE) ,linetype="solid" ,aes(colour = "GFDL.ESM4"))+
        stat_function(fun = dLO, args =list(mu= 73.086,sigma=1.485,log=FALSE) , linetype="solid",aes(colour = "MPI.ESM1.2.HR"))+
        stat_function(fun = dNO, args =list(mu= 139.373,sigma=2.895) ,linetype="solid",aes(colour = "MRI.ESM2"))+
        stat_function(fun = dLO, args =list(mu= 134.221,sigma=2.158,log=FALSE) ,linetype="solid", aes(colour = "NorESM2.MM"))+
        stat_function(fun = dNO, args =list(mu= 107.372,sigma=2.232) ,linetype="solid" ,aes(colour = "TaiESM1"))+
        scale_color_manual("Data Types",breaks = c("Observed", "CMCC.ESM2","ECEARTH3","ECEARTH3.CC","ECEARTH3.Veg","GFDL.CM4","GFDL.ESM4","MPI.ESM1.2.HR","MRI.ESM2","NorESM2.MM","TaiESM1"),values = c("Black","green", "blue","brown","darkgreen","red","cyan","yellow4","aquamarine4","slateblue4","magenta4"))+
        labs(x = "Monthly average Precipitation (mm)", y = "PDF") + 
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
              axis.title.x = element_text(face="plain", colour="black", size = 12),
              axis.title.y = element_text(face="plain", colour="black", size = 12),
              legend.title = element_text(face="plain", size = 10),
              legend.position = "none")
    
    plot2<- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(xlower , xupper)), aes(x = x)) + 
        xlim(c(xlower , xupper)) + stat_function(fun = pNO, args =list(mu= 85.433,sigma=2.208) ,linetype="solid", aes(colour = "Observed"))+
        stat_function(fun = pSN2, args =list(mu= 97.847,sigma=2.896,nu=5.882,log=FALSE) , linetype="solid",aes(colour = "CMCC.ESM2"))+
        stat_function(fun = pIGAMMA, args =list(mu= 4.520,sigma=2.336,log=FALSE) , linetype="solid",aes(colour = "ECEARTH3"))+
        stat_function(fun = pRG, args =list(mu= 93.062,sigma=2.233,log=FALSE) ,linetype="solid" ,aes(colour = "ECEARTH3.CC"))+
        stat_function(fun = pRG, args =list(mu= 94.296,sigma=2.237,log=FALSE) ,linetype="solid" ,aes(colour = "ECEARTH3.Veg"))+
        stat_function(fun = pSHASH, args =list(mu= 112.241,sigma=12.133,nu=9.419,tau=9.743,log=FALSE) ,linetype="solid", aes(colour = "GFDL.CM4"))+
        stat_function(fun = pRG, args =list(mu= 101.101,sigma=2.372,log=FALSE) ,linetype="solid" ,aes(colour = "GFDL.ESM4"))+
        stat_function(fun = pLO, args =list(mu= 73.086,sigma=1.485,log=FALSE) , linetype="solid",aes(colour = "MPI.ESM1.2.HR"))+
        stat_function(fun = pNO, args =list(mu= 139.373,sigma=2.895) ,linetype="solid",aes(colour = "MRI.ESM2"))+
        stat_function(fun = pLO, args =list(mu= 134.221,sigma=2.158,log=FALSE) ,linetype="solid", aes(colour = "NorESM2.MM"))+
        stat_function(fun = pNO, args =list(mu= 107.372,sigma=2.232) ,linetype="solid" ,aes(colour = "TaiESM1"))+
        scale_color_manual("Data Types",breaks = c("Observed", "CMCC.ESM2","ECEARTH3","ECEARTH3.CC","ECEARTH3.Veg","GFDL.CM4","GFDL.ESM4","MPI.ESM1.2.HR","MRI.ESM2","NorESM2.MM","TaiESM1"),values = c("Black","green", "blue","brown","darkgreen","red","cyan","yellow4","aquamarine4","slateblue4","magenta4"))+
        labs(x = "Monthly average Precipitation (mm)", y = "CDF") + 
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
              axis.title.x = element_text(face="plain", colour="black", size = 12),
              axis.title.y = element_text(face="plain", colour="black", size = 12),
              legend.title = element_text(face="plain", size = 10),
              legend.position = "right")
    
    p<- plot_grid(plot1, plot2, labels = "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reduced the number of stats plotted to make it easier to see what's going on.

As the legends are the same for both graphs you only need one set of `scale_x_manual`.

Both linetype and colour need to be in the call to aes to appear in the legend.

To merge the two legends give both legends (colour and linetype) the same name in the call to `labs`.

You may find you need to define additional linetypes as the standard set comprises 6.

```r
library(gamlss)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

xlower= 50
xupper= 183


plot1<-ggplot(data.frame(x = c(xlower , xupper)), aes(x = x)) + 
  xlim(c(xlower , xupper)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dNO, args =list(mu= 85.433,sigma=2.208), aes(colour = "Observed", linetype="Observed"))+
  stat_function(fun = dSN2, args =list(mu= 97.847,sigma=2.896,nu=5.882,log=FALSE), aes(colour = "CMCC.ESM2", linetype = "CMCC.ESM2"))+
  stat_function(fun = dNO, args =list(mu= 107.372,sigma=2.232), aes(colour = "TaiESM1", linetype = "TaiESM1"))+
  labs(x = "Monthly average Precipitation (mm)", y = "PDF") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="plain", colour="black", size = 12),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="plain", colour="black", size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(face="plain", size = 10),
        legend.position = "none")

plot2<- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(xlower , xupper)), aes(x = x)) + 
  xlim(c(xlower , xupper)) + 
  stat_function(fun = pNO, args =list(mu= 85.433,sigma=2.208), aes(colour = "Observed", linetype="Observed"))+
  stat_function(fun = pSN2, args =list(mu= 97.847,sigma=2.896,nu=5.882,log=FALSE), aes(colour = "CMCC.ESM2", linetype = "CMCC.ESM2"))+
  stat_function(fun = dNO, args =list(mu= 107.372,sigma=2.232), aes(colour = "TaiESM1", linetype = "TaiESM1"))+
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("Observed", "CMCC.ESM2", "TaiESM1"),
                       values = c("Black","green", "magenta4"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(breaks = c("Observed", "CMCC.ESM2", "TaiESM1"),
                       values = c("solid", "dashed", "longdash"))+
  labs(x = "Monthly average Precipitation (mm)",
       y = "CDF",
       colour = "Data types",
       linetype =  "Data types") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="plain", colour="black", size = 12),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="plain", colour="black", size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(face="plain", size = 10),
        legend.position = "right")

p<- plot_grid(plot1, plot2, labels = "")
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Oww, Thanks I have done It.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but the command should be

```
 geom_line(aes(colour=Observed, linetype=Observed), size=1)
```

So for `plot 1` and `plot 2`

```
plot1<-ggplot(data.frame(x = c(xlower , xupper)), aes(x = x)) + 
   xlim(c(xlower , xupper)) + 
   stat_function(fun = dNO, args =list(mu= 85.433,sigma=2.208), aes(colour = "Observed", linetype="Observed"))+
        stat_function(fun = dSN2, args =list(mu= 97.847,sigma=2.896,nu=5.882,log=FALSE) ,aes(colour = "CMCC.ESM2", , linetype="CMCC.ESM2"))+
        stat_function(fun = dIGAMMA, args =list(mu= 4.520,sigma=2.336,log=FALSE) , linetype=ECEARTH3,aes(colour = "ECEARTH3"))+
        stat_function(fun = dRG, args =list(mu= 93.062,sigma=2.233,log=FALSE) ,linetype=ECEARTH3.CC ,aes(colour = "ECEARTH3.CC"))+
        stat_function(fun = dRG, args =list(mu= 94.296,sigma=2.237,log=FALSE) ,aes(linetype="ECEARTH3.Veg", colour = "ECEARTH3.Veg"))+
        stat_function(fun = dSHASH, args =list(mu= 112.241,sigma=12.133,nu=9.419,tau=9.743,log=FALSE) , aes(linetype="GFDL.CM4",colour = "GFDL.CM4"))+
        stat_function(fun = dRG, args =list(mu= 101.101,sigma=2.372,log=FALSE)  ,aes(,linetype="GFDL.ESM4", colour = "GFDL.ESM4"))+
        stat_function(fun = dLO, args =list(mu= 73.086,sigma=1.485,log=FALSE) ,aes(, linetype="MPI.ESM1.2.HR", colour = "MPI.ESM1.2.HR"))+
        stat_function(fun = dNO, args =list(mu= 139.373,sigma=2.895) ,aes(,linetype="MRI.ESM2", colour = "MRI.ESM2"))+
        stat_function(fun = dLO, args =list(mu= 134.221,sigma=2.158,log=FALSE) , aes(linetype="NorESM2.MM", colour = "NorESM2.MM"))+
        stat_function(fun = dNO, args =list(mu= 107.372,sigma=2.232)  ,aes(,linetype="TaiESM1", colour = "TaiESM1"))+
        scale_color_manual("Data Types",breaks = c("Observed", "CMCC.ESM2","ECEARTH3","ECEARTH3.CC","ECEARTH3.Veg","GFDL.CM4","GFDL.ESM4","MPI.ESM1.2.HR","MRI.ESM2","NorESM2.MM","TaiESM1"),values = c("Black","green", "blue","brown","darkgreen","red","cyan","yellow4","aquamarine4","slateblue4","magenta4"))+
        labs(x = "Monthly average Precipitation (mm)", y = "PDF") + 
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
              axis.title.x = element_text(face="plain", colour="black", size = 12),
              axis.title.y = element_text(face="plain", colour="black", size = 12),
              legend.title = element_text(face="plain", size = 10),
              legend.position = "none")

plot2<- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(xlower , xupper)), aes(x = x)) + 
  xlim(c(xlower , xupper)) + 
  stat_function(fun = pNO, args =list(mu= 85.433,sigma=2.208), aes(colour = "Observed", linetype="Observed"))+
  stat_function(fun = pSN2, args =list(mu= 97.847,sigma=2.896,nu=5.882,log=FALSE), aes(colour = "CMCC.ESM2", linetype = "CMCC.ESM2"))+
  stat_function(fun = dNO, args =list(mu= 107.372,sigma=2.232), aes(colour = "TaiESM1", linetype = "TaiESM1"))+
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("Observed", "CMCC.ESM2", "TaiESM1"),
                       values = c("Black","green", "magenta4"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(breaks = c("Observed", "CMCC.ESM2", "TaiESM1"),
                       values = c("solid", "dashed", "longdash"))+
  labs(x = "Monthly average Precipitation (mm)",
       y = "CDF",
       colour = "Data types",
       linetype =  "Data types") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="plain", colour="black", size = 12),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="plain", colour="black", size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(face="plain", size = 10),
        legend.position = "right")

p<- plot_grid(plot1, plot2, labels = "")
p
```